# MediaWiki installation hangs after exporting LocalSettings.php

Tags: mediawiki

I just finished going through the MedaWiki installation steps, and have moved LocalSettings.php to the root directory of the wiki, but the wiki fails to load. Instead, when I go to the wiki index page, the request hangs and does nothing.

attempted /var/www recursive permissions:
777 nobody:nogroup
777 www-data:www-data
777 sshUser:sshUser

Server settings:
Ubuntu 15.04   Lighttpd    php5-fpm  php5-cgi  mysql-server

Other websites load, it's just MediaWiki that fails after exporting LocalSettings.php to the MediaWiki root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. What I did was the follow the steps on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9566 to apt-get install more php files:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client phpmyadmin php5-cgi php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-ming php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-fpm php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-suhosin
```

After doing that, and changing the permissions to the wiki root directory to 777, I deleted the old LocalSettings.php and restarted the installation to create a new one. It worked with the new LocalSettings.php.